# why the following inequality is true?

Tags: calculus

In lecture today teacher wrote that

$$ \frac{ e^{-1} e^n n! }{n^n} > 0 \iff \frac{e^n n! }{n^n} > e $$

but, I dont see how this can be true. can someone explain to me if this a true statement?

Comment: Is the $0$ supposed to be a $1$ instead? I think it should be a $1$.

Comment: that is how he wrote it in the board

Comment: Then he might have written wrongly, I suggest asking him.

Comment: I agree with Camille. I think the 0 has to be a 1.

Answer (score 3):

Note: Consider the case $n=1$. You will see that
\begin{align}
\frac{e \cdot 1!}{1}=e
\end{align}
which is not strictly greater than $e$. Suppose $n>1$, then we see that
\begin{align}
\log n! =\sum^n_{k=1}\log k > \int^n_1 \log x\ dx = n \log n -n +1 
\end{align}
which means 
\begin{align}
n! > e\left(\frac{n}{e} \right)^n
\end{align}
for all $n>1$.

So the condition

\begin{align}
e^{-1}\frac{e^nn!}{n^n}>0 \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \ n!>e\left(\frac{n}{e} \right)^n
\end{align}
is essentially true because the right hand side is always true when $n>1$.

Comment: Shouldn't the $n=2$ case be $e^2 \cdot 2! \;/\; 4 \gt e$ which is true?

Comment: @dxiv Thanks. I have made the correction.

Comment: That will be easy to adapt once the OP corrects the question to $\gt 1$ rather than $0$ ;-)